# Letter sequences in a series

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let's suppose we have a set of letters $\{a,b,c,x,y,z\}$. How many series (6-letter words, for example $abbxaz$) can we create provided that we have at least one sequence $xy$?

At first I tried to split it into three cases, with only one $\textbf{xy}$ (e.g. $ab\textbf{xy}az$), two (e.g. $\textbf{xy}ya\textbf{xy}$) and three (easiest part, as there is only one combination $\textbf{xy}\textbf{xy}\textbf{xy}$), but it doesn't seem to be the right idea, as I have to consider also all of the subsets and dependencies between them (e.g. when I have to have $\textbf{xy}$ once then $\_ \ \_\ \textbf{xy} \_ \ \_$ would differ from $\_ \ \textbf{xy} \_ \ \_ \ \_$ and I also need to exclude all the intersections with all the cases when $\textbf{xy}$ occurs twice or thrice). I could also try permuting and using symmetry wherever it's possible, but still, it probably doesn't vary much from what I wrote above. Is there an elegent way to do that? I somehow can't believe that I have to write all the cases possible.

Comment: Infinitely many?  You have `xy`, `xya`, `xyaa`, `xyaaa`, `xyaaaa`, ..., `xyaaaaaaaaa....aaa`, etc... for each quantity of `a`'s you wish among others.  Are you looking for the number of such words of a particular length?  Are you looking for each letter to have been used exactly once or at most once?

Comment: If of any length, then you can have far more than just your three cases.  It will be more convenient to look at the opposite count, the number with *no* substring `xy`.  It is also easy to count where we don't care about whether or not there is any substring `xy`.  The count you would want then would be the difference of these.

Comment: @JMoravitz my bad. I consider only 6-letter series/words. I also tried to find all the sequences with no $\textbf{xy}$ but it didn't seem to be much simpler.

Comment: I suggest using the inclusion/exclusion principle: naively count for all placements of the xy (for example (. . . x y . ) the number of words with the xy in that place. The problem is that we have counted for example x y a x y b twice, but we can substract the amount of words with 2 xy's in (and then something silimar goes wrong in case we have 3 xy's). Does this help?

Comment: @AntonV. well, my solution would eventually come down to the  inclusion-exclusion principle, that part is clear. What I would struggle with is a huge amount of cases, as, let's say: if I start with xy, then I can suppose that the following letter is either x (and then only 5 possibilites) or different (so 6 possibilities), and also next three letters depend upon the previous ones. Horrible, and yet it's only for xy____ (luckily at the same time for ____xy). One of many cases. It's just a whole lot of work and I wonder if it could be speeded up.

Comment: I still think it easiest to do this via recursion.  You have $a_1=6$ is the number of valid length $1$ strings and $a_0 = 1$ the emptystring as base cases.  (*If you dislike the empty string as a base case, then $a_2 = 35$*).  Let $b_n$ be the number of these who did end in an `x`, so $b_0=0$ and $b_1=1$.  Let $c_n$ be the number who did not, so $c_n = a_n-b_n$.  We have that $b_{n+1}=a_n$ by taking any valid length $n$ string and appending an $x$.  We have $c_{n+1}=4b_n+5c_n$ by appending a non-`x` to the end except the case of appending a `y` after an `x`.

Comment: The idea is that at first, you 'don't care' about double counting: so the first guess is as follows: 'I have 5 places for the xy (anywhere between the 4 remaining letters) and each of the remaining 4 letters can be 1 of 6 possibilities, so the total is $5*6^4$. This is wrong, since we counted each word with exactly 2 xy's twice and each word with exactly 3 xy's thrice. To fix this, we count the words with two xy's and substract that total from $5*6^4$. If we use the same naive technique (choose 2 places for the xy between the 2 remaining letters..) the only error is for 3 xy's...

Comment: @AntonV. is it possible that the result is 6265?

Comment: I think that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIG HINT

If you let $P_i$ be the  words  with 'xy' in the $i$th and $i+1$th places, then $|P_i|=6^4$ for $1\le i \le5$.

Then the inclusion-exclusion principle takes care of all your concerns about double counting. You only have to calculate

$$\sum |P_i|-\sum|P_i\bigcap P_j|+|P_1\bigcap P_3\bigcap P_5|.$$

Comment: Thanks! The answer is 6265, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I get!